# Results nesting into array

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I'm using ReactNative + React Redux.

My Reducer:

```
const initialState = {
    categories: []
}


case "FETCHING_SUCCESS":
      return {
        ...state,
        isAdding: false,
        categories: [...state.categories, action.data]
      }
```

The data that I receive is :

```
[
 {id:1, name: 'name01', someId: 11}, 
 {id:2, name: 'name02', someId: 22}, 
 {id:3, name: 'name03', someId: 33}
]
```

If I do:

```
case "FETCHING_SUCCESS":
      return {
        ...state,
        isAdding: false,
        categories: action.data     // <= Notice This
      }
```

I get the data fine - console.log("CATEGORIES: ", this.props.caregories); :

[image]

But I want to append the received data to the existing data. So if I do:

`categories: [...state.categories, action.data]`

I get an Array into an array :

[image]

And on further API calls, multiple arrays nested into the primary one.

How do I solve this? I just want the primary array and not arrays nested in the primary array. I can `map` and show the data from the primary array. I don't understand how else I'm supposed to append the data.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you meant to do is `categories: [...state.categories, ...action.data]`.

Answer (score 1):

Your codde should be:

```
case "FETCHING_SUCCESS":
      let newCategories = [...state.categories, ...action.data];
      return {
        ...state,
        isAdding: false,
        categories: newCategories
      }
```

Check this snippet out :)

```js
var state = {
    categories: [1,2,3,4],
    isAdding: true,
    done: false
};
    let data = [5,6,7,8];
    let newcategories = [...state.categories, ...data];
    state = {
       ...state,
       isAdding: false,
       categories: newcategories  // <= Notice This
    }
console.log(state)
```